# Stack with type parameters in Java

Tags: java, generics, stack

Im trying to get a stack working in close to the latest Java (Java 13).

Something like:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
```

The error message I get is

> The type Stack does not take parameters

However, all the examples I have seen online are with parameters.

How should I build a (non-primitive) stack?

=====++=========

Addendum:

So, I got it to work fine by importing:

import java.util.Stack;

which is strange because I already had an import:

import java.util.*;

Anyway, I wont bother figuring it out further as it works now.

Comment: Is that your exact code? Or are you doing something like `... = new Stack<String>(someObject);`

Comment: First of all, is `Stack<>` a library class or is it your own code? Also, since Java 7 you don't have to specify generic arguments in the constructor as they can be inferred. I don't know Java 13 that good, but what if the use of the generic parameter is not just useless, but also prohibited in this version? Anyway, I'd try to use `new Stack<>()` instead

Comment: 1) Make sure you imported [`java.util.Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), not some other stack implementation, and that you haven't created a class of your own named `Stack`. --- 2) The javadoc of `Stack` recommends that you use `Deque` / `ArrayDeque` instead *("Deque interface and its implementations should be used in preference to Stack")*.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can copy/paste and get the the same error you are asking about.

Comment: The java 13 [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html) for Stack confirms it is still a parameterized class in modern Java. That is assuming we're using java.util.Stack and not some other arbitrary implementation.

Comment: Please do not use the cumbersome old legacy class `Stack`. Use a `Deque` instead, with `ArrayDeque` as implementation. The `Stack` class is old and got superseded by better classes that do the same job.

Comment: Downvote and voting to close as the question is unclear, it lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score -3):

I would not fool around with a library, since whatever you are doing often requires some specialized need. It is much better to make a stack that does specifically what you want, rather than try to hammer a library to bully it into a useful shape. Below is a typical implementation of a stack in Java. It is currently set up to hold ints, but if I want to hold, say, strings, then I just adjust it.

```
public class Utility_Stack {
    final static int DEFAULT_Capacity = 1000;
    int capacity = 1000;
    int xTop = 0;
    String[] aString;
    int[] aInt;
    double[] aDouble;
    private Utility_Stack(){}
    public static Utility_Stack create(){
        Utility_Stack stack = new Utility_Stack();
        stack.aInt = new int[ DEFAULT_Capacity ];
        return stack;
    }
    public void push( int item ){
        xTop++;
        if( xTop >= capacity ){
            int iNewCapacity = capacity * 7 / 5;
            int[] new_stack = new int[ iNewCapacity + 1 ];
            System.arraycopy( aInt, 0, new_stack, 0, aInt.length );
            aInt = new_stack;
            capacity = iNewCapacity;
        }
        aInt[ xTop ] = item;
    }
    public int peek(){ return aInt[ xTop ]; }
    public int pop(){
        int top = aInt[ xTop ];
        aInt[ xTop ] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        if( xTop > 0 ) xTop--;
        return top;
    }
    public void reset(){ xTop = 0; }
    public boolean isEmpty(){ return xTop == 0; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fool around with a library"? Are you suggesting that we avoid modifying standard Java API classes? Or are you suggesting that we avoid using classes from the standard Java API and write our own?

Comment: This doesn't look like any sort of 'typical" Java implementation given the non-standard naming conventions, improper capitalization, non-private variables, lack of parameterized typing, ambiguous variable names, and so on.